# Span and image size on hover enlarge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found an bit of css that allows you to enlarge the image on hover, and for the most part it works great.

My problem is I have been dealing with all images of a certain size, and it worked great for them, now I am on another page with two different sizes, so I must make another css class.

http://jsfiddle.net/fj8hP

The jsFiddle does not play the same way as my site is... but it gives a better visualization of my problem.

The part above the image, the white box, seems to have a direct correlation with the image size. I had all short width and long images, so it was fine, but now I am dealing with wider images, and do not like the box spanning the whole image. So if I set the width to 300px in this part

```
ul.enlarge2 span {
    position:absolute;
    height:10px;
    width:300px;
}
```

the image will show at the desired size. I want it to be no larger than 100, and centred on the image. Any ideas?

Here is the CSS:

```
ul.enlarge2 {
    list-style-type:none;
    /*remove the bullet point*/
    margin-left:0;
}
ul.enlarge2 li {
    display:inline-block;
    /*places the images in a line*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    /*resets the stack order of the list items - later we'll increase this*/
    margin:5px 10px 0 10px;
}
ul.enlarge2 img {
    background-color:#eae9d4;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(132, 132, 132, .75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
ul.enlarge2 span {
    position:absolute;
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
    left: -9999px;
    background-color:white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family:'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    text-align: center;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75));
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius:8px;
}
ul.enlarge2 li:hover {
    z-index: 150;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.enlarge2 span img {
    padding:2px;
    background:#ccc;
}
ul.enlarge2 li:hover span {
    top: 100px;
    /*the distance from the bottom of the thumbnail to the top of the popup image*/
    left: 0px;
    /*distance from the left of the thumbnail to the left of the popup image*/
}
ul.enlarge2 li:hover:nth-child(2) span {
    left: -200px;
}
ul.enlarge2 li:hover:nth-child(3) span {
    left: -200px;
}
ul.enlarge2 img, ul.enlarge span {
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The only allowable child of a UL is LI.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want. What does "the image will short at the desired size" mean? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I meant it will show at the desired size. @isherwood

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're after, but I'd guess that you need to take the width and height off the image wrapper, so it flows properly around the image, and resize the image instead.

Comment: I will put the site online and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put the text inside `span1` and put whats in `ul.enlarge2 span` into a new tag in css for `span1`. that way you can manipulate that white box easier. also you need `display:block` and `margin:0 auto` to make `span1` to get centered.

```
ul.enlarge2 span{
position:absolute;
left: -9999px;
background-color:white;
}
```

this is all you need in that part everything else goes into `span1` tag.

here is the fiddle with a different picture http://jsfiddle.net/JVQp7/

it is probably not the most elegant way of doing this and it might not validate as i have put div inside span etc.

if you want the box to appear before image put `span1` before it.
http://jsfiddle.net/JVQp7/1/

Comment: Ah hah! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, when I hit 15 rep I'll give it an upvote!

Comment: @BrettD you can still select it as solution. you need 50 rep for upvote.